# Label is not toggled, if cursor is moved while mousedown

Tags: html, css, forms, mouseevent

I've just realized a bug (or maybe feature) regarding the standard behavior of a label tag.

The click event is usually triggered after mouse is up again. As long as the cursor is not moved while mouse is down, the click event is triggered and toggles the labeled input field (e.g. checkbox).

> **Is this the standard mouse behavior to NOT toggle the input field while moving cursor if mousedown? And how to avoid it?**

```css
label {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: firebrick;
  border: 1px solid currentcolor;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="test" />
<label for="test">Click here and move your cursor while mousedown</label>
```

---

Comment: I think that's standard behavior.  The same is true of anchors and buttons.  You might not want to muck with it if users expect the usual behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know all browsers handle the distinction between `click` and `mousedown` similar. Mousedown is triggered when the mouse button is down. Click is only triggered after the mouse is up again and the cursor hasn't moved in the meantime. This not just true for labels, but for links and buttons as well and is the standard behavior.

If you don't want the text to be selected, you can try using `user-select: none`.

```css
label {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: firebrick;
  border: 1px solid currentcolor;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="test" />
<label for="test">Click here and move your cursor while mousedown</label>
```